# Extracting Spring Utility Project as Runnable Jar

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to export my project (which compile without error and is running locally) into `runnable jar` file in order to execute it from a server.

`Export` went without an error however whenever I am trying to do
`java -jar Project.jar`

I get

> Starting camel log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport). log4j:WARN Please initialize the
>   log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could
>   not resolve bean definition resource pattern [META-INF/spring/*.xml];
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [META-INF/spring/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>           at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:216)
>           at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:156)
>           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>           at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:150)
>           at pl.camel.project.Main.boot(Egzekutor.java:31)
>           at pl.camel.project.main(Egzekutor.java:21) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [META-INF/spring/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>           at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.isJarResource(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:413)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:280)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1227)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
>           ... 15 more

it is not finding `/META-INF/spring` directory, how?

tree:[image]

Comment: Does /META-INF/spring/ exist?

Comment: is it in the exported jar?

Comment: It looks like whole META-INF is not there.. I have no idea how I can export it to be include jar because editor in eclipse does not have any more options..

Comment: @jamp the strange thing is that when i try to `jar -tf Project.jar |grep spring` I get `resources/META-INF/spring/
resources/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml
resources/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml`